# Leaflet error when moving marker: setLatLng is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet, and practicing using the Open Notify API (http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/) to track the ISS on a map. After creating a marker and adding it to the map, I call the following function provided by Open Notify:

```
function moveISS () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json?callback=?', function(data) {
        var lat = data['iss_position']['latitude'];
        var lon = data['iss_position']['longitude'];

        iss.setLatLng([lat, lon]);
        isscirc.setLatLng([lat, lon]);
        map.panTo([lat, lon], animate=true);
    });
    setTimeout(moveISS, 5000); 
}
```

This successfully gets the lat and lon values, but then I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: iss.setLatLng is not a function
```

I know the setLatLng method exists from the Leaflet documentation (http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#marker-setlatlng), so why is it not being called? Is there another plugin that needs to be installed first before it is recognized?

Comment: `iss` is not defined ?

Comment: That was it. I thought I had defined it outside the function, but there must've been a syntax error somewhere I didn't see. Ran around in circles thinking the issue was with setLatLng.

Answer (score 0):

From the open-notify sample, there was a comment in the sample code:

> See leaflet docs for setting up icons and map layers

The code shown in the question does not show the definition of `iss`.  The error suggests it might not be a Leaflet `marker`.

The `iss` and `isscirc` might be defined like in the Leaflet sample code:

```
var iss = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>The International Space Station</b>").openPopup();

var isscirc = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
```

The starting coordinates above are arbitrary and will be updated on the first call to `moveISS`.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg3mvubx/) for a working example adapted from the Leaflet sample code.

Comment: This was exactly it. Problem was I had initialized my variables, but wrong. Careless mistake on my part.